# Should I delete a downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, challenges

Some times ago, I posted a question that is now -3. I got some good answers that helped me (and I accepted one of them), but the -3 score hints that the question is not good.
 Should I delete it?

Comment: In addition to what Mego said, what you can do to *prevent* badly received challenges in the future is to post your ideas [in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get feedback before the challenge goes live (you can get downvotes in the sandbox, but they won't affect your rep, and then you still have a chance to address any criticism without invalidating answers). The sandbox is not a silver bullet, but it can greatly help in gauging interest and ironing out the details of a challenge.

Comment: Deletion isn't the only option: you could also try to improve it. I'll make more specific comments on the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101750/45941), you can't delete it. You can only delete your own questions if they don't have answers. This is the way it works across the entire network - the philosophy is, if it wasn't bad enough to delete before getting answers, the best thing to do is live and learn.

Comment: +1 The exact criteria for this are [slightly more subtle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/212780), but that's the gist of it.